# Can I perform manual hardware clicks on elements in watir-webdriver?

Tags: click, watir, watir-webdriver

In Watir I could do this using Win32API and the fact that the elements were OLE-accessible. In watir-webdriver this is no longer the case. I'm not looking to perform a .click, or a .fire_event('click'), but actually take the system mouse pointer and use it on an element. Preferablly to click-and-drag.

My problem is locating the elements on the screen, as the watir-webdriver location and the Win32API location do not appear to be compatible - is there a way to find the element and hardware click on it? If so, will the same code work on two different machines?

Thanks :)

PS. I am aware of the click-and-drag code floating about that is in pure w-webdriver code, but it seems to not like a ZK interface very much.

Also this post has been edited for me to include the Watir tag, but it should be emphasised that the difference between the functionality of Watir and Watir-Webdriver is the reason for this question, and that I am using the latter.

Comment: The big problem I'd have doing this is that you have an IE only solution, but hey if that's what the customer needs and doesn't care about doing this in FF or Chrome, well then..

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden This is true. All of our customers use IE as a minimum, as our software is run on self-contained touchscreen units. Agreed, though, it is a pain, and I will be testing non-hardware-mouse methods on other browsers.

Comment: I believe there is a drag and drop feature request in the watir-webdriver project on Git, you may want to go comment on it if this is something you need.  That's one of the primary ways that people working on the project get feedback from users.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden Someone submitted a feature request and I added my weight to it with a comment, but that was created in April and I added the comment in August so I'm not going to put my eggs in that basket just yet :). When I understand the code under the hood some more then hopefully I can contribute some useful bits to the project and drag-and-drop will be of particular interest!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of an IE based solution, have you seen this [CheezyWorld Blog Posting](http://www.cheezyworld.com/2010/12/20/drag-and-drop-in-watir/) on the topic?

Comment: That's the one that uses ole_object to locate the (see the top_edge method). That used to be my go-to for old Watir scripts, and well loved, but it unfortunately won't work in watir-webdriver.